# Appium error occurred while processing the command

Tags: ios, iphone, eclipse, appium

I'm new to `appium` and i'm running some automation scripts on a real device. When i run that particular script on simulators. There are no issue. But when i try to run the same on real device then i get the below mentioned error.

`An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.`

Original error:

`Bad app: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app.`

App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.

```
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stack-trace information)
```

Any type of help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SafariLauncher is used when you are trying to automate the safari browser. The safari launcher has to be built for iPhone (real device). It looks like the safari launcher that is built in is built for simulator, which is why the fruitstrap/ideviceinstaller (app installer used by appium-ios) complains as bad app.

To compile the safarilauncher for your real device.
1. Download safarilauncher code from github
    https://github.com/budhash/SafariLauncher
2. Compile the code using your developer provisioning profile (having wildcard as bundle id)
3. Place this safari launcher app for the real device automation.

To compile the safari launcher follow this link for detailed info:

https://discuss.appium.io/t/error-installing-safari-launcher-on-real-device-appium-v1-3-7/3793

Comment: i did the same steps but no success @Vinayak

Comment: What happened when you tried to do that ? Whats the error ?

Comment: Same error, but we figured out, we were missing something else. Thanks

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please accept the answer.